# there is a gap on the right of the images when i zoom out

Tags: css

I have 2 images with `100vh` and `50vw` each on display, the image height scales when I when i zoom out, but the width stays the same and there is a large gap of nothing there, any thoughts of how i can fix this, i added `object-fit:cover` to both elements,

i want the images to fit the whole screen even if i zoom out

```css
#item1 { 
  width:50vw; 
  height:100vh; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  min-height: 973px; 
  min-width: 1000px; 
  object-fit: cover; 
}

#item2 { 
  width:50vw; 
  height:100vh; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  min-height: 973px; 
  min-width: 1000px; 
  object-fit: cover;
```

```css
.the-images { 
  display: flex; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 10; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}

.the-images img { 
  object-fit: cover; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
}

img { 
  width: 100vw; 
  height: 100vh; 
  object-fit: cover; 
}
```

`item1` and `item2` are a part of the div `the-images`

i want to keep the min-width because every item is a different size

EDIT: NEW PROBLEM
That fixed that problem but now the problem is I need images with 1100px width. I want the `min-width: 1100px` to stay but when I zoom out I dont want a gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `min-width` and `min-height` from both elements and removed this part of the code

```
.the-images img { 
  object-fit: cover; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

it was holding back the picture from being 50vw at all times
because of `width: 100%`